# Can't see Toolchain option in Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: xcode

So. My mac running 10.11.5 El Capitan and I have latest Xcode. Also I have Latest Xcode 8 Bata 2.

As it is described here 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AlternativeToolchains.html

I can switch between toolchains. But I have no option in Xcode>Preferences>Components. Am I missing something ?

Also there are no Toolchain folder neither in ~/Library/Developer/ and or /Libarary/Developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer myself. In case you wondering were is it Toolchain thing you should first dowload it from here
https://swift.org/download/#snapshots

**Trunk Development (master)**

Choose one that you need. Download the .pkg file and install it. Restart Xcode and Toolchains will appear Preferences.